# Секунды в timestamp

Tags: python

Стоит задание получить timestamp из данных о секундах. Например, прошло 125 секунд и надо превратить это в timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

`Timestamp` представляет из себя число секунд, прошедших с `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. Поэтому коротким ответом на ваш вопрос будет `125`, если началом отсчёта считать `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.

Более полный ответ должен учитывать момент времени от которого идёт отсчёт секунд.

Пример:

```
In [22]: from datetime import datetime as DT

In [23]: DT.strptime('2019-01-01 13:14:15', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timestamp() + 125
Out[23]: 1546344980.0
```

Т.е. если мы включили секундомер `2019-01-01 13:14:15 UTC` то ровно через 125 секунд `timestamp` составит `1546344980`.

PS ещё более подробный ответ должен будет сначала перевести локальное время в `UTC`.